# How to optimize working with array in the following code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

Is there a way to make the following code faster? It's becoming too slow, when length of array is more than 1000 records, especially in IE6.

```
  dbusers = data.split(";");
  $("#users").html("");
  for (i = 0; i < dbusers.length; i++) {
     if ($("#username").val() != "") {
        if (dbusers[i].indexOf($("#username").val()) != -1) {
           $("#users").append(dbusers[i] + "<br>");
        }
     } else {
        $("#users").append(dbusers[i] + "<br>");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Obligatory "don't use IE6" comment in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Welcome to SO @stee1rat. Where does the data come from? Do you know which part is slow exactly?

Comment: Thanks, Pekka!

The data come from company's mssql servers. It's just a login list.

Answer (score 5):

Minimize the amount of work you do in the loop. Don't add stuff to the DOM in the loop, create a string.

```
var dbusers = data.split(";");
var username = $("#username").val();
var userlist = "";
if (username == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < dbusers.length; i++) {
        userlist += dbusers[i] + "<br>";
    }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < dbusers.length; i++) {
        if (dbusers[i].indexOf(username) != -1) {
            userlist += dbusers[i] + "<br>";
        }
    }   
}   
$("#users").html(userlist);
```

Comment: +1 Lots of small DOM insertions are much slower than one big DOM insertion.

Comment: wow, i'm slow.  Shouldn't be watching Superman Returns on telly, it sucks anyway :-)

Comment: This is not a very good idea - building up a string like that is terribly slow in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Faster than those by far (**especially** in IE!) is to build your string as an array (yes, really) and then concatenate it at the end:

```
var dbusers = data.split(";"), username = $('#username').val();
$("#users").html($.map(dbusers, function(_, dbuser) {
  if (username == '' || dbuser.indexOf(username) > 0)
    return dbuser + '<br>';
  return '';
}).get().join(''));
```

The `$.map()` routine will build an array from the return values of the function you pass. Here, my function is returning the user string followed by the `<br>`.  The resulting array is then turned into a string by calling the native `join()` routine.  Especially when you've got like 1000 things to work with, this will be **much** faster than building a string with repeated calls to `+=`! Try the two versions and compare!

Comment: Your code is incorrect.  The first parameter passed to the callback is the data, not the index; remove your `_, `.  Also, `$.map` returns an array, not a jQuery object, if an array is passed, so remove `.get()` too.

Answer (score 2):

Use a document fragment.

You can perform more optimizations, too, like removing that nasty if and creating the nodes yourself.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    dbUsers = data.split(';'),
    dbUsersLength = dbUsers.length,
    curDbUser,
    usernameVal = $('#username').val();

for(i = 0; i < dbUsersLength; ++i) {
    curDbUser = dbUsers[i];

    if(curDbUser.indexOf(usernameVal) !== -1) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(curDbUser));
        frag.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}

$('#users').empty().append(frag);
```

I made a tool to benchmark all the current answers: http://dev.liranuna.com/strager/stee1rat.html

ghoppe's and mine seem to be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support `querySelector`, so lookups can be particularly slow.  Keep HTML manipulation within loops to a minimum by reducing the number of appends you do, each one has a regular expression run on it to extract the HTML and convert it to a DOM object.  Also work in some micro optimisations where you can, might improve performance a little especially over thousands of iterations.

```
var usersEl = $("#users"); // reduce lookups to the #users element
var result  = "";          // create a variable for the HTML string
var unameVal = $("#username").val(); // do the username value lookup only once
dbusers = data.split(";");
usersEl.html(""); 

// Store the length of the array in a var in your loop to prevent multiple lookups
for (var i = 0, max = dbusers.length; i < max; i++) { 
  if (unameVal !== "") { 
    if (dbusers[i].indexOf(unameVal) != -1) { 
      result += dbusers[i] + "<br>"; 
    } 
  } else { 
    result += dbusers[i] + "<br>"; 
  }
} 
usersEl.html(result);  // Set the HTML only once, saves multiple regexes
```

Comment: IE6 is absolutely terrible about repeated string concatenations. Always build big strings as arrays that you join() together at the end!

Comment: @Pointy: I didn't realize string concatenation in IE6 was so bad.  I guess I learned something new today :-)

Comment: @Andy glad to help - I encourage you to try it out, because it's really jaw-dropping how slow that browser can be on something so simple!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but unfortunetly this advices didn't help much. It's still awfully slows.. Actualy i can generate this list on the server side, while making ajax-request and get completed html to put it on the page, but the problem is that i want to add filtering functionality on the page, that's why i have to store that array with names in memory.

Comment: I know this thread is way done by now, @AndyE, but I notice you're setting the HTML every iteration of your for loop. That makes it even slower than @stee1rat's original. I'm sure it's just a typo.

Comment: @ghoppe: oops :-) it was a mistake, thank you for pointing it out - I like to edit mistakes like this even though the thread is old.